# Dynamically use bleuimp jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using the `blueimp` JQuery `fileupload`, however I would like to use it dynamically. I've got about 5 elements on my webpage and each of them should call the javascript function (auto upload) when a file was selected. Below is the basic version of `bleuimp` JQuery file upload. Instead of using a div called `#fileupload`, I have 5 divs with ids `#fileupload1` to `#fileupload5`.

I would like to get the javascript code working for all 5 `#fileupload` id's using a single javascript block. So basically I am looking to use the code below but for all 5 elements. Is there a way to do that and if so does someone have an example for me? Thanks for any help.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                alert('DONE');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Maybe not the best one but so far it works for me.

```
$('.dp-upload-container').each(function () {
// Code from $(function() { }); here using different ID's and classes dynamically.
});
```